# Read raw Ethernet using Qt

Tags: qt, network-programming, raw-ethernet

I have a device which sends out a raw (Layer 2) Ethernet packet which I need to read and decode using a Qt based C++ Windows application.  I believe I can do it using the winpcap libraries but would prefer a Qt way if possible.

Comment: There's no "Qt way" of replacing pcap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a raw packet from pcap, wrap into `QByteArray`, munch on it using `QDataStream`. Qt doesn't include a replacement for pcap, so that's out of the question.